# CakePHP Helper Question

Tags: php, cakephp

What is difference between this:

```
$html->link
```

and

```
$this->Html>link
```

The first one works fine, but the second one always throws errors, but is used often in documentation over the first one. What is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the first syntax to refer to the HTML helper **in a view** (like you normally would).

The second syntax is used to refer to the HTML helper **in another helper**. [Example](http://book.cakephp.org/view/101/Creating-Helpers).

Answer (score 0):

The second syntax is newer and was introduced with CakePHP 1.3.0: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1572/New-features-in-CakePHP-1-3#View-Helpers-1574. And you can use this syntax not only in other helpers as mentioned by kizzx2, but also in your views.

Getting errors with this syntax means you are using an old CakePHP version.

Comment: maybe you use $html somewhere as a variable. this way you destroy the helper (or you maybe didnt include it in the app_controller...)